# How to display the process tab in pgadmin?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm using pgadmin to run backups and restores, and I want to monitor its progress.

I've seen in the docs the "process" tab
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/processes.html#process-watcher

I just can't find it in my ui - how can I enable it? or where can I find it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is your pgAdmin version? (Help-> About pgAdmin -> version)
This is only available from 6.13 and above.

Comment: OK - good catch, I was in 4.1 (opened the wrong icon on my machine) but still once I got the processes window, I've ran a restore and it's still empty (says no rows found) any tips?